# Error/bug PHP SIMPLE HTML DOM PARSER

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my table:

```
<table class="datatable"><thead></thead><thead>
<th scope="col"><font><font>Position</font></font></th>
<th scope="col">Group</th>
<th scope="col">Drivers</th>
<th scope="col">Time</th>
<th scope="col"><font><font>Points</font></font></th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td><font><font>1°</font></font></td><td><font><font>GROUP</font></font></td><td><a href=“#”>AA, </a><a href="#">BB, </a><a href="#">CC, </a><a href="http://#">DD</a></td><td><font><font>00’11’’22</font></font></td><td><center><font><font>1111</font></font></center></td></tr><tr><td class="alt"><font><font>2°</font></font></td><td class=“alt”><font><font>GROUP</font></font></td><td><a href=“#”>AA, </a><a href="#">BB, </a><a href="#">CC, </a><a href="http://#">DD</a></td><td class="alt"><font><font>00’11’’22</font></font></td><td class="alt"><center><font><font>1111</font></font></center></td></tr><tr><td><font><font>3°</font></font></td><td><font><font>GROUP</font></font></td><td><a href=“#”>AA, </a><a href="#">BB, </a><a href="#">CC, </a><a href="http://#">DD</a></td><td><font><font>00’11’’22</font></font></td><td><center><font><font>1111</font></font></center></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I can't get just the coloumn of position, time and points, I used PHP SIMPLE DOM PARSER, but the problem is when i do a foreach for tr, he repeat so many times the results and don't get the single row, try the code please:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
$e = $html->find('table');
$str = str_get_html($e);
foreach($str->find('tr') as $key=>$g){
            if($key == 0)
                continue;
            echo $g;
    }
$html->clear();
    unset($html);
```

my code is this try it.

Comment: Don't use the tag `<font>`! It is deprecated. The code for your table is not complete and not indented well. Please correct this for better readability.

Comment: I corract the table code, but thit's a table i'd like to parse, how to remove font tag with the parser?

Comment: The code provided for the table is still missing the opening `thead` tag. The code witihin `tbody` is placed in a single line going from here to Japan. Please correct this, readability helps your helpers.

Comment: I thought you generate the table, so I pointed out not to use deprecated HTML elements.

Comment: Now the code is complete, i rechecked it, no more missing. Thanks, the result is the same so tell me some solutions of you found it please

Comment: Perhaps format the html so somebody has a chance

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will give you an array containing each row in an associative array

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('table-3.html');

$data = array();
foreach($html->find('table tr') as $row) {
    $dataRow = array();
    $dataRow['position'] = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $dataRow['group'] = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    $dataRow['drivers'] = $row->find('td',2)->plaintext;
    $dataRow['time'] = $row->find('td',3)->plaintext;
    $dataRow['points'] = $row->find('td',4)->plaintext;
    $data[] = $dataRow;
}

print_r($data);

$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

Comment: it's perfect but after few records he get an error:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: @Roberto post the full table so we can catch errors too :)

Comment: can you send me an email? so I can let you the link for do tests, for privacy can't insert link here, my email is kuroashi90@gmail.com

Comment: @Roberto the source html is very badly formatted. `thead` tag opened twice, opened `a` tags without closing tags, quotes for parameters are used on and off. The html source needs a lot of work before it can be safely parsed.

Answer (score 0):

If in my case have a bad html to parse, just solved this problem thanks to

```
strip_tags(
```

function, for clean html tag wrong or useless, and thanks to that I clean the code, for finally parse without problems.

Before clean I just saved DOM with

```
$str->save('result.htm');
```

Thanks to that, I found the problem and fixed, with strip_tags!!